# Time series forecasting on GCP AutoML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

According to [this](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/12/using-automl-for-time-series-forecasting.html) Google AI's blogpost, Google designed an AutoML end-to-end pipeline with a specialized search space for time series forecasting. This AutoML forecasting solution has already been tested on several Kaggle datasets.

In GCP AI Platform>AutoML, I see no option to train a time series forecasting model.

Is this AutoML forecasting solution already publicly available in GCP? If so, how to access that?

Comment: I would check these claims first. If you go to https://www.kaggle.com/c/m5-forecasting-accuracy/leaderboard you have the choice between private and public leaderboard. If you look at the private leaderboard - which is the only valid way to evaluate - there is no sign of Google AutoML. If you go to public leaderboard there is an entry place 136 from a deleted user (blog said 138, but users move up when others get disqualified). This user dropped to *bottom* 0.5% on the private leaderboard! So much for overfitting with 500 cpus.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a "Forecasting" option for tabular data if you use AutoML through Vertex AI. It's still in beta but you can try the [Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/automl-forecasting-with-vertex-ai).